# html - CSS Counter Increment does not work

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: sections subsection;
}
.manual h1:before {
  counter-increment: sections;
  content: "Section " counter(sections)". ";
}
.manual h2:before {
  counter-increment: subsection;
  content: counter(sections)"." counter(subsection)" ";
}
.manual h2 {
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #3a7486;
}
```

```html
<div class="manual">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>1.1</h2>
  <h2>1.2</h2>
  <h2>1.3</h2>
  <h2>1.4</h2>
  <h1> 2</h1>
  <h2>2.1</h2>
  <h2>2.2</h2>
  <h2>2.3</h2>
  <h2>2.4</h2>
</div>
```

I want to get the results exactly as you see in the html. However,after the second H1 instead of having 2.1, I see 2.5. am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4):

You have to reset counter subsection for each H1:

```
h1 {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}
```

```css
body {
 counter-reset: sections  subsection;
}
h1 {
 counter-reset: subsection;
}
.manual h1:before {
 counter-increment: sections;
 content: "Section " counter(sections) ". ";
}
.manual h2:before {
 counter-increment: subsection;
 content: counter(sections) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
.manual h2{
 line-height: 60px;
 color: #3a7486;
}
```

```html
<div class="manual">
<h1>1</h1>
<h2>1.1</h2>
<h2>1.2</h2>
<h2>1.3</h2>
<h2>1.4</h2>
<h1> 2</h1>
<h2>2.1</h2>
<h2>2.2</h2>
<h2>2.3</h2>
<h2>2.4</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset subsection

check this snippet

```css
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

h1 {
    counter-reset: subsection;
}

h1::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section) ". ";
}

h2::before {
    counter-increment: subsection;
    content: counter(section) "." counter(subsection) " ";
}
```

```html
<div class="manual">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <h2>1.1</h2>
  <h2>1.2</h2>
  <h2>1.3</h2>
  <h2>1.4</h2>
  <h1> 2</h1>
  <h2>2.1</h2>
  <h2>2.2</h2>
  <h2>2.3</h2>
  <h2>2.4</h2>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Consider accepting @Banzay solution he was the first person to give the right answer

Comment: @Banzay Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi everyone,
I ran the code with some modifications as follows:
CSS was the same, but I put H2 in different sections  and I noticed that I do not get the expected result. Just remember when using the code, H1s and their related H2s should be in the same section.

Comment: can you add a fiddle that would help us to understand

Answer (score 0):

As @Geeky and @Banzy stated you need to have conter-reset on H1. However, please note that do not separate h1 and all of its related h2s by sections. If you use

, they all have to be placed in the same section. Have a look at the html below.
With the same css, only the first section that includes the first h1 and its related h2s work fine. As, you can see the second section does not work properly.

```
<div class="manual">
    <section>
        <h1> heading 1</h1>
        <p>test</p>
        <h2>1.1</h2>
        <p>test</p>
        <h2>1.2</h2>
        <p>test</p>
        <h2>1.3</h2>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1> heading 1-Second time</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h2>2.1</h2>
    </section>
    <div>
        <section class="test">
            <h2>2.2</h2>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <section id="test">
            <h2>2.3</h2>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>heading 2-second time</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```